# Specifying an axis label

Tags: graph, label, stata

My Stata code is as below. In this code I want to specify the `ymlabel as the 10th entry of the variable` higher_ACME_control`. I tried

```
ymlabel(higher_ACME_control[10]......
```

but it didn't work. How can I do this?

```
twoway rarea higher_ACME_lower_control higher_ACME_upper_control higher_rho, color(ltblue) || line higher_ACME_control higher_rho, lcolor(blue) || ///
function y=higher_ACME_control[10], range(-1 1) lpattern(dash) lstyle(foreground)  ///
yline(0, lstyle(foreground)) xline(0, lstyle(foreground)) xlabel(#19) ymlabel(.11579794, labsize(tiny) labcolor(red) format(%9.2g)) ylabel(-2(0.5)2, angle(vertical) labsize(vsmall)) ytitle("ACME (control)") xtitle("rho") ///
legend(order(2 "point estimate of" "the causal effect"  1 "confidence interval")) saving(sens_higher_ACME_control ,replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
ymlabel(`= higher_ACME_control[10]')
```

should work, although we have no way to check with your data.

You could, and perhaps should, do this in two steps

```
* add a comment on why you are doing this
local label1 = higher_ACME_control[10]
twoway ... ymlabel(`label1')
```

The device extends to other axis labels should you wish to use them.

That said, here are some reservations.

1. The code is utterly sensitive to sort order. Change the sort order, and you will almost certainly see a different axis label.
2. If you use a local macro to store the desired label, you must execute all the relevant code together, as otherwise the definition of the macro won't be visible to the command that refers to it.